# +-10v variable power supply

Tags: voltage, variable

I need to generate a variable voltage ranging from +10v to -10v in order to control a motor driver.  What are ways to generate this voltage?

To clarify: the motor driver takes +-10V as an input. +10V is full forward, -10V is full reverse, with voltages in between being differnt speeds, and 0 being stop.

Comment: In order to control a motor driver? Usually the driver itself should have a way to adjust the motor voltage.

Comment: If your motor driver has outputs of +/-10V you can connect a pot from +10 to -10 and use the wiper as the input.

Comment: Moved comment into edit on original post

Comment: If @SpehroPefhany comment was not good enough, how complex do you want to make of something that is simple? If we are missing some crucial detail, we can do no more for you.

Comment: The motor drives uses the +-10V as a control signal, and I doesn't have any outputs, except for the motor, you have to supply your own control voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh... Spehro Pefhany already gave you a great clue. Shop for a power supply that puts out +/- 10 volts or more likely +/- 12 volts. It does not have to supply even 1/2 amp to work.

Buy a 10 K potentiometer (and a knob) and connect its CW and CCW inputs to your +/- 10 volts. Connect the wiper to your motor controller. Connect the common grounds for speed control and the power supply together. Done.

The speed controller will likely ignore any voltages above 10 volts or less than - 10 volts.

Comment: I had a feeling such things existed, thanks for the answer.  Can you link to any general models?

Comment: On-line sources for these low cost parts would be Digi-key, Mouser or Allied.

Comment: An explanation for the down vote would be nice, down voter.